# Angular Ui-Router-Extras | Trying to implement sticky states, but not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, angular-ui-router-extras

Well, I have this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tOYGQnX0ensEkVFy6YQt?p=preview) trying to simulate my situation:

I have **3 tabs** and the idea is that the user type a word on the textbox, and when click the button, **an angular service** returns an answer (result) from a DB according to the typed on the textbox (I have simulated this process with requesting data to a json file, so it is not important whatever you type, always will return the whole data) and populated a table in another view.

What's my goal? Well, I need to preserve every view intacted per tab. In other words, when the user click on a tab (changing the states) and returns to another, the data that was requested, could be there (and also what was typed on the search box).

**EDIT:**

I have an array containing my definitions:

```
var parentStates = [
      {state : 'tab1', url: '/tab1/', template: 'tab1.html', s: false, d: true},
      {state : 'tab2', url: '/tab2/', template: 'tab2.html', s: false, d: true},
      {state : 'tab3', url: '/tab3/', template: 'tab3.html', s: false, d: true},
      {state : 'tab1.table', url: '', template: 'table.html', s: true, d: false},
      {state : 'tab2.table', url: '', template: 'table.html', s: true, d: false},
      {state : 'tab3.table', url: '', template: 'table.html', s: true, d: false}
    ];
```

And I define my states dinamycally, in this way:

```
parentStates.forEach(function(childName){
        $stateProvider
          .state("home." + childName.state, {
            controller: "itemController", resolve: { $title: function() { return childName.state; } },
            url: childName.url,
            templateUrl: childName.template,
            sticky: childName.s,
            deepStateRedirect: childName.d
          })
      });
```

Applying only sticky to the states `home.tab*.table`. This works, but not as espected. For example, what I type on search box, dessapear when I change the tab. I need that the content from the 3 arrays (mentioned below) could bee keeped per tab. That's my issue.

I have 3 arrays:

```
$scope.Model.items;
$scope.Model.filteredlist;
$scope.Model.expenses;
```

and I use a function called `$scope.clear_arrays` to clear the data on the arrays (even on the `$stateChangeSuccess`). I don't know if this is ok to get what I want.

I know I have to use the great [angular-ui-router-extras](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras)`(sticky states)` library, but I don't know how to apply it in my case. I have tried with:

```
sticky: true,
deepStateRedirect: true,
```

but does not works. Some ideas, some help?

**EDIT:**

As the [docs](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky) says, I need exactly this part:

> *... The states for a tab in the application does not get exited when switching to one of the other tabs. The user should be able to switch back and forth between tabs without any interruption in their workflow.*

Comment: Do your tabs need to be dynamic? I see you're automating a lot of things, and that is adding a significant amount of complexity to accomplishing the sticky states. For example one of the things we need to do for sticky states is something like this for the ui-views:
`<div ng-show="$state.includes('main.tab1')" ui-view="tab1"></div>
<div ng-show="$state.includes('main.tab2')" ui-view="tab2"></div>`

Comment: The shortest code to reproduce your issue should be in your question; with the plunkr as secondary. If the plunkr link 404s; then this question becomes useless for future visitors.

Comment: @sergiocruz  Thanks for your answer ! Yes, I know it's a little bit complex, but I really need that the tabs could be dynamic. Mabye you can give me some help, or some example to understand how sticky states works with tabs.  _Obrigado pela sua ajuda meu amigo !_

Comment: @robe007 For us to re-open the question and solve your issue, you'll need to put the code in. That's why we explicitly have a close reason for this issue.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Ok, I have edited my question adding more explanation and code. Also I updated the plunkr.

Comment: @robe007 This is the closest that I got to it: http://plnkr.co/edit/gLn19DMyKBTwZRMpv6Fo let me know if this works for you and I will be glad to post a detailed answer on what I had to do to make this work. Here's a screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/1B0p1S3S2o3o

Comment: @sergiocruz Nice and thanks, but, where is the view with the table?

Comment: @robe007 I removed it, but could easily add it back in using a directive or something like that. I just wanted to show you the actual states being preserved (sticky). But yeah, having that extra route for the table wasn't quite working out so I figured we could have all of that in a directive. Would that work for you?

Comment: @sergiocruz Yes, of course, I think will work great ! I need the table, because there is where the data will be visible for the user. Can you, please update the plunkr, and add the directive with the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few design decisions to keep in mind when using ui-router-extra's sticky states:

1. Use a named view for each state, and hide/show them as these states become active. This makes if you think about it... if we remove those views from the DOM entirely then the state of that part of your app is gone (think of a partially typed input box for example). Here's an example:

   `<div ng-show="$state.includes('main.tab1')" ui-view="tab1"></div>`
2. Use a shared controller for your tabs. Because of the nature of sticky states, in order to share a state, it's best (and thus far the only way I've found) to make this work. This step is quite simple, just don't assign a controller to your sub-states and you should be good to go.

Below is a simple state definition taking advantage of the steps described above, including a parent route, controller-less child, and sticky states:

```
$stateProvider
.state('main', {
  url: '/',
  controller: 'MainCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'main',
  templateUrl: 'state-main.html'
})
.state('main.tab1', {
  url: '/tab1',
  sticky: true,
  views: {
    tab1: {
      templateUrl: 'state-tab1.html',
    }
  }
})
```

Here is a very simplistic example using sticky states:
http://plnkr.co/edit/SCHExh4DYKFd9Kq3UbaA

For your app, I applied the principles laid out above and removed the table sub-states as those were complicating things a bit. So to simplify I took the liberty to wrap the table in a directive and passed the data into it from the parent scope.

The usage of that directive became pretty simple (feel free to rename it more appropriately):

```
<table-list ng-if="Model.tab1.length > 0" list="Model.tab1" />
```

Keep in mind that `Model.tab1` contains the array of elements for the `tab1` state (remember shared controller).

Finally, here is your app working with sticky states: http://plnkr.co/edit/gLn19DMyKBTwZRMpv6Fo

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks to [sergiocruz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1354614/sergiocruz) for his answer. I have made another changes, and this is the final and awsome app: [http://plnkr.co/edit/DJffZ0gx4sc3KjK0gZUf?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/DJffZ0gx4sc3KjK0gZUf?p=preview) !